# truetype font optimization

Tags: fonts, truetype

I use an embedded font in my iPhone application which manage latin, chinese and korean characters. 
it is too heavy, because it contains many other types of characters (indian, arab, russian, ...).
Is there any tool which can delete unused characters in the ttf file ? not one by one but by selecting the wanted languages ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator
Select the *EXPERT...* option and then *Custom Subsetting...*.
Now you can select the languages you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fontsquirrel is very sensitive to license stuff. Some fonts may be blacklisted.
You can also use FontForge and simply do a multiselect and "Clear" in popup menu. If you use Windows, there is [windows build](http://www.mpetroff.net/software/fontforge-windows/).

Comment: Here's an article about how to do it in FontForge, step by step. It's a bit dated, but the steps still work; I just tested and reduced a file from 156KB to 35KB. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Create_a_new_TrueType_font_using_a_subset_of_characters_from_an_existing_TrueType_font